# matplotlib equal spacing between datapoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying do plot some data with the x axis showing equidistant spacing between the data points.

**The code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sizes = [1400, 1600, 1700, 1875, 1100, 1550, 2350, 2450, 1425, 1700]
prices = [245, 312, 279, 308, 199, 219, 405, 324, 319, 255]

plt.xlim([1000, 2500])
plt.ylim([0, 500])
plt.xlabel("sizes")
plt.ylabel("prices")

plt.scatter(sizes, prices)
plt.show()
```

**How it looks:**
[image]
**How I want it to look:**

[image: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/04/simple-understand-gradient-descent-algorithm.html]

So the distance between each two neighboring points is equal.

Comment: This seems not to make much sense. If the xaxis is an axis with units and you do have the according values (here `sizes`), the complete plot would be falsified by doing what you request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems your graph is just for representation purpose. The numbers on the x-axis do not need to be on a scale. To plot this, you must create a `x` axis list which is actually to scale and just replace its labels by the elements of your `sizes` list. The following code shows how to do this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sizes = [1400, 1600, 1700, 1875, 1100, 1550, 2350, 2450, 1425, 1700]
prices = [245, 312, 279, 308, 199, 219, 405, 324, 319, 255]

plt.ylim([0, 500])
plt.xlabel("sizes")
plt.ylabel("prices")

x = [a for a in range(len(sizes))]
plt.scatter(x,prices)
plt.xticks(x, sizes)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Turns out it doesn't make much sense after all but your answer is correct. Thank you!